# Searchview in actionbar in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, searchview

I am creating an android application. In the application I have a login page. After login a userlist is displayed. The userlist activity is `HomeActivity.java` that contains two fragments named as `UserListFragment.java` and `ChatFragment.java` The userlist is getting displayed from **firebase**.

The UserListFragment.java contains an actionbar which has a search menu and logout menu. The logout menu works fine but the search isn't working. The search icon gets displayed but when I search something it doesn't show anything i.e. no filters. I am using firebase to display the userlist.

I don't want the searchview to be displayed in ChatFragment.java

I tried various various various solutions. But none worked for me.

Here is the code.

**UserListFragment.java**

```
public class UsersListFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
Activity activity;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private static final String TAG = "UsersListFragment";
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private ListView listView;
private List<UserData> users;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
Timer myTimer;
View view;
ActionBar actionBar;
private static final String PREFRENCES_NAME = "setPreferences";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
String partnerKeyValue;

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static UsersListFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    UsersListFragment fragment = new UsersListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Global.getInstance().unreadMessageUsers.clear();
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_userlist,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i(TAG,newText);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}


private void logoutUser(){
    Intent I = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(I);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSearch :
            return true;

        case R.id.menuLogout :
            logoutUser();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**menu_userlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/menuLogout"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            users = (List<UserData>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new Filter.FilterResults();       

            List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalValues != null) {

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).toString();
                        if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your filter method working ? Did you check the value of the `results` return variable

Comment: @Dibzmania my **results** variable contains this value 

**android.widget.Filter$FilterResults@5a9dec**
Everytime I type some alphabet some value is getting generated for each alphabet I type in search as above. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Dibzmania I guess I am getting null value. When I tried to print **results.values** I got null exception error. How can I resolve it.?

Comment: Your filter method looks ok. It might return an empty results see if search string does not match any data.The problem is that you are not setting the filtered data on the adapter. After calling `  adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);` , you need to call to set adapter data with the return of the previous method

Comment: @Dibzmania Can you please provide the code.?
Btw Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: You need to share your fragment and adapter code for that. Did you read my comment and tried to change as per that

Comment: @Dibzmania I added the code. Have a look. Also tell me where I need to set the adapter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by myself. It may help someone else. :)

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            addAll((List<UserData>) results.values);
            arrayList = (List<UserData>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            List<UserData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<UserData>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<UserData>(arrayList); 
            }


            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();


                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                    String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();

                    if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }

            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following segment of code  -

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        clear();
        addAll((List<UserData>) results.values)
        users = (List<UserData>) results.values; // has the filtered values

        notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
    }
```

This mostly would solve the problem. but there are lot of inconsistencies in your source code. You are extending `ArrayAdpater` which already implements the `Filterable` interface.

Also review why you need the below state variables  -

```
private List<UserData> messages;
private List<UserData> users;
private List<UserData> mOriginalValues;
```

Please note that you are extending `ArrayAdapter` and you are passing the initial data set in the constructor. Any change in data set thereafter, you need to reset it on the parent `ArrayAdapter`. Just changing the state variables in your child class, is not gonna help.

Comment: The code you suggested for edit leads to app crash.
`private List<UserData> messages;`
    `private List<UserData> users;`
    `private List<UserData> mOriginalValues;`

users and mOrigninalValues I have used for the filter method. I am new to android and hence used the code from some source. messages I am using for the unread message count, I need to show next to the user's name.
If you could provide me with some changes and guide me, what should I change. It will be really helpful to me. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: what's the crash stack trace ? I have not actually run the code, so there is every possibility that it might. But the idea is to clear the underlying data and add the new data.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference on this line. 

 addAll((List<UserData>) results.values);

Comment: The return from your filter method is NULL. you need to add NULL checks.

Comment: Okay. Now I don't get any error. But when I search then the list becomes null,no search suggestions and after closing the search menu, previous list is also not getting restored.

Comment: The filter issue is resolved.
I am facing some other issue though. When I am clicking on some user name and then I go to `ChatFragment.Java` but when I return back, only the searched names are visible. But I want to display the complete list. How to do that.?

Comment: That's because your adapter is persisting it's last data set which was the filtered set. If you want all the users, then you have to set the data again.        `clear();`
        `addAll(/*pass in the complete user set*/)   If your OP is fixed, then mark the question as answered.

Comment: Where will I have to write addAll again.?

Comment: may be in your fragments `onResume`